# Change space style using listings package

Tags: spacing, listings

I'd like to make all space characters in the code gray. Is there an easy way to do this?
Is there something like `spacestyle` (I've commented it)?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{book}

\usepackage[UTF8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian, ukrainian]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}

\lstset{%
    language     = [77]Fortran,
    basicstyle   = \ttfamily,
    keywordstyle = \color{black},
    stringstyle  = \color{Gray},
    showspaces   = true,
%   spacestyle   = \color{Gray} 
    numbers      = left,
    numberstyle  = \ttfamily \color{black}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
      PROGRAM HELLO
      WRITE(*, *) "Hello, World!"
      END PROGRAM
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]
Also I want to change all spaces to gray bullets. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `listings` package uses `\lst@visiblespace` for these spaces so you just need to define it:

[image]

Here's the latex code. I removed your font encoding as I didn't want to generate all of the required fonts.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}

\makeatletter
\def\lst@visiblespace{$\color{Gray}\bullet$}
\makeatother

\lstset{%
    language     = [77]Fortran,
    basicstyle   = \ttfamily,
    keywordstyle = \color{black},
    stringstyle  = \color{Gray},
    showspaces   = true,
%   spacestyle   = \color{Gray}
    numbers      = left,
    numberstyle  = \ttfamily \color{black}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
      PROGRAM HELLO
      WRITE(*, *) "Hello, World!"
      END PROGRAM
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm interested in how did you find information about `\lst@visiblespace`?

Comment: @klimenkov Glad to be of help. To find this I used `kpsewhich listings.sty` to find the style file and then I searched for `showspaces` to find out how the package changed the output of the spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Those visible-space characters tend to distract the reader (well, me, anyway); I can understand why you would want them to be fainter than they naturally appear when `showspaces` is set.

The `listings` package defines no such `spacestyle` key, but you can always create one, if you want. See below.

[image]

### How did I find out about `\lst@visiblespace`?

I knew `showspaces` was the key responsible for typesetting visible-space characters in place of spaces, so I searched for the definition of that key in [`listings.dtx`](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.dtx):

```
\lst@Key{showspaces}{false}[t]{\lstKV@SetIf{#1}\lst@ifshowspaces}
```

I then searched for `\lst@ifshowspaces`, which led me to the following line:

```
\let\lst@outputspace\lst@visiblespace
```

Then I searched for `\lst@visiblespace`, which led me to the definition of that macro:

```
\def\lst@visiblespace{\lst@ttfamily{\char32}\textvisiblespace}
```

My custom `spacestyle` key uses a modified version of that original definition.

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{book}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}

% new custom key called spacestyle
\makeatletter
\lst@Key{spacestyle}{}
  {\def\lst@visiblespace{{#1\lst@ttfamily{\char32}\textvisiblespace{}}}}
\makeatother

\lstset{%
    language     = [77]Fortran,
    basicstyle   = \ttfamily,
    keywordstyle = \color{black},
    stringstyle  = \color{Gray},
    showspaces   = true,
    spacestyle   = \color{Gray},
    numbers      = left,
    numberstyle  = \ttfamily \color{black}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
      PROGRAM HELLO
      WRITE(*, *) "Hello, World!"
      END PROGRAM
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm interested in how did you find information about `\lst@visiblespace`?

Comment: @klimenkov See my last edit.